# Build argv with unique_ptr or RAII?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

I have a library function that has the following signature `func(int argc,char** argv)`, where argv is an array of c-strings, and crafted manually according to the enclosing environment of the application.

Can I use `unique_ptr` to manage the memory of `argv` instead of allocating/deallocating them via `new`/`delete` operators ?

Comment: When I’ve had to call into a function like that, I make a class with a `std::vector<std::string>` for storage, and a `std::vector<char*>` pointing to the `s.c_str()` of each.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use unique_ptr to manage the memory of argv instead of allocating/deallocating them via new/delete operators ?

Certainly. There's pretty much no case where you cannot replace new/delete with `std::unique_ptr`.

That said, there are potentially more convenient alternatives for arrays of `char`, such as `std::string` or perhaps `std::vector`.

Comment: I am stuck with library. 
For me I prefer to use strings vector.

Answer (score 0):

Your library function appears to want to be called as if it was main.

`main`'s arguments are a bit special, in that the `char**` should really be `char const*const*`.  Some programs don't respect that, but most do.

But by far the easiest way to do it is this:

```
int call_fake_main( int(*fake_main)(int, char**), std::vector<std::string> args ) {
  std::vector<char*> ptrs;
  ptrs.reserve(args.size());
  for (auto& str:args)
    ptrs.push_back(str.c_str());
  return fake_main( static_cast<int>(ptrs.size()), ptrs.data() );
}
```